# Finding the smallest centrally symmetric region that contains a convex planar region

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, computational-geometry

1. Given a convex polygonal region C, how does one find/characterize the smallest zonogon (centrally symmetric convex polygon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zonogon) that contains C?

*Note 1:* In question 1, smallest could mean least area or least perimeter. So, one can also ask which C maximizes the difference between its least area and least perimeter convex centrally symmetric container.

2. Given a convex planar region C, how does one find/characterize the largest zonogon contained within C?

*Guess:* At least the largest area internal zonogon of C seems to have its center on the medial axis of C. Not sure about the least perimeter one - this zonogon could degenerate into a zero area one in some cases.

*Note 2:* Analogous questions can be asked about *axisymmetric* containers - and containees - of C.

*Note 3:* Some similar questions are recorded at [Curves of constant width that contain triangles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403485/curves-of-constant-width-that-contain-triangles), [Smallest triangles that contain 2D convex regions with reflection symmetry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/345552/smallest-triangles-that-contain-2d-convex-regions-with-reflection-symmetry) and linked pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question 1, in the minimum-area setting, has been studied by Guibas, Nguyen and Zhang (SODA 2003). They prove the following algorithmic result:

> **Theorem 4.5** The minimum area zonotope containing a set of $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be computed in $O(n \log^2 n)$ [time].

If you set the center of the zonotope at $O$, then the zonotope must contain the original vertices (of your convex polygon) and their reflections (with respect to $O$), and the minimum-area solution is the convex hull of those two point sets. So you can define a function $f$ that maps $O$ to the minimum area. They prove that this area function is unimodal and piecewise affine, and they design an efficient algorithm that finds its minimum.

*Guibas, Leonidas J.; Nguyen, An; Zhang, Li*, Zonotopes as bounding volumes, Proceedings of the fourteenth annual ACM-SIAM symposium on discrete algorithms, Baltimore, MD, USA, January 12–14, 2003. New York, NY: Association for Computing Machinery; Philadelphia, PA: Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics (ISBN 0-89871-538-5/pbk). 803-812 (2003). [ZBL1092.68697](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1092.68697).

(A freely available version of their paper is [in ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220779216_Zonotopes_as_bounding_volumes).)

Here is an illustration by myself of a minimum-area zonogon around a triangle. The contours illustrate zonogon area as a function of the centerpoint $O$. Observe that the function is indeed piecewise affine (as proven by Guibas et al.), and that somewhere inside the input triangle, there is a nonzero-size region (dark blue) where the area function attains its minimum, so $O$ can be chosen freely from that area (here: randomly).

[image: Zonogon around triangle]

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully the other aspects of question 1 and question 2 have similarly nice answers.